# Properly use .ui with pyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

my goal is to bring a .ui interface in a python program.
It barely works but I would like to improve it since I can't obtain exactly what I want.

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('sss.ui')
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.ui)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For now I have to create a layout to paste my sss.ui to.
The QVboxLayout dosen't respect the stylesheet I setup in Qt Designer.
How can I use my sss.ui directly ?
Do I need to convert it ? I unable to find the pyuic5 in my Qt install ...

Answer (score 0):

First, obtain the `pyuic5` executable. Try to reinstall PyQt, search for it in `bin` directories (system-wide, virtualenv, etc.).

Once you have it, you should compile your `.ui` file using it:

```
pyuic5 sss.ui > ui_sss.py
```

Then use it in your code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication

from ui_sss import Ui_sss  # if toplevel widget in .ui file is also called "sss"


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_sss()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: QApplication is imported from PyQt5.QtWigdets for me.
But evertything works fine now.
Why convert instead of using the .ui ? faster , easier ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't run this code by myself, I'll fix it. First, it is provided in documentation examples. Second, I'm not sure if you could operate dynamically dynamically added objects, but you could check it yourself. Third, this way you could get all sorts of IDE assistance when writing code for it. And yes, I'm not sure how dynamic `.ui` file parsing is done, but I think it is faster to have ready Python code than parse XML.